All matroid polytope is a generalized permutohedron
In many texts, the authors say something like "a matroid polytope lives in the family of generalized permutohedra". We can quickly check the veracity of this claim by describing the matroid polytope $P_M$ using the inequality description of $P_M$. This description is actually given by:
$$
P_M = \{(x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n : \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = r, \sum_{i \in I} x_i \leq r(I), \forall I \subseteq \{1, \dots, n\} \}
$$
where $M$ is a matroid over $[n] = \{1, \dots, n\}$ defined by its collection of bases $\mathcal{B}$ and with rank $r$.
Now, for me, it is not trivial to arrive at this definition starting from the usual definition of $P_M$, because the usual notation is:
$$
P_M = \text{conv}\{e_A : A \in \mathcal{B}\} \quad \text{with} \quad e_A = \sum_{i \in A} e_{i}.
$$
Well, maybe I can rewrite it as something like:
$$
P_M = \text{conv}\{e_A : A \in \mathcal{B}\} = \left\{\sum_{k} \lambda_{k} \left(\sum_{i \in A} e_{i} \right) : \lambda_i \geq 0, \sum \lambda_i = 1 \right\}.
$$
But how can I get the inequality description of $P_M$ using the last fact? Any hints or suggestions? I'd appreciate it.
Note:It may be that my appreciation is not entirely true, and to arrive at this description of the matroidal polytope it is not even necessary the usual definition, but I do not see clearly the way to describe what I mentioned.

It is a theorem (often attributed to Gelfand-Goresky-MacPherson-Serganova but I think known/proved earlier by Edmonds) that matroid polytopes are $0,1$-polytopes whose edges are parallel to $e_i-e_j$, i.e., the roots of the Type A root system. What Edmonds calls a "polymatroid" is a lattice polytope satisfying the same condition, i.e. whose edges are parallel to $e_i-e_j$ (so the difference is we do not require the vertices to have $0,1$ coordinates). The polymatroids are exactly the integral generalized permutohedra, i.e. generalized permutohedra that are lattice polytopes.

I assume that such a description can be found in the authors' joint paper called Combinatorial geometries, convex polyhedra, and schubert cells, or not?

Yes, absolutely, that's the seminal GGMS paper and has this result in it. But like I said, Edmonds's earlier work (which as I understand it was more in the context of optimization) was overlooked for a long time in the algebraic combinatorics/algebraic geometry community and is now slowly being more appreciated. Some people now prefer the term polymatroid to generalized permutohedron, for example.

Although all these facts (like that generalized permutohedra and polymatroids are basically "the same things") are well-known to experts, I agree it can be hard to find precise statements and explanations in the literature. Maybe look at "Deformation Cones of nested Braid fans" by Castillo and Liu (https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.01899)

@SamHopkins It is curious what you say, I was not clear about the existence of polymatroids and it can be interesting. I appreciate your help, I still have a small question and it is, where does such a description by inequalities of the matroidal polytope come from, I saw it for the first time in a version of the article of Ardila, Benedetti and Doker, concretely proposition 2.5. https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.3947

I'm not 100% sure the paper of Ardila, Benedetti and Doker is the first paper to write down the facet description of matroid polytopes (like I said the history of all these results is a bit murky), but it's a good paper and a good one to quote for that result if you need it.

Thank you very much for your clarifications!
